# Can we get the chat link in the right sidebar back on the main site?

Tags: bug, status-completed, beta, chat

I notice that our chat room, [Ham Shack](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11162/ham-shack), is overall less active than it used to be, even though the Q/A activity has been improving a bit recently (all subjective, I have no numbers to back this up). I also notice that the sidebar widget that shows chat rooms hasn't been showing up on the main site at all lately (though I just saw it briefly on this meta, and I could be wrong about it never showing up).

**Is there some broken association that can be fixed to make it show up on main as well as meta reliably?** I think having chat more obviously available will help improve general participation indirectly.

I recognize that [it might be that public beta sites don't have it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127282/show-the-chat-box-in-the-sidebar-for-public-beta-sites), but comments there indicate that it should be showing up on question/answer pages (and in fact it does on meta, but not on main).

---

**New observation July 8:** The “n People Chatting” sidebar item is showing up frequently (though not on the front page), but *it does not list the Ham Shack room or any other* — oh wait, I said something in the room and now it does after a few minutes. Whew. So, problem fixed? I'll wait to make other observations or for official word.

Comment: I see it on Meta, but not on the main site. Odd. Interestingly enough, I don't see any link to the chat room on *this* page.

Comment: I think it's part of a random selection of sidebar choices. But it also seems to be *never* on *any* page on the main.

Comment: I'm hoping someone from SE can fix this up easily or tell us what's going on.

Comment: I'm looking into this now, I'll post a proper answer once someone in NYC wakes up that I can ping.

Comment: @TimPost Any updates? It seems to be working this minute — fluke or did someone poke something?

Comment: From what I can gather, it's not going to advertise a room that has been idle for quite a while. However, I'm going to see if we can get one of our chat wizards to weigh in on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this worked itself out as the activity in the room picked up:

[image: there it is :)]

If it drops out again completely, *and* the room has been active for the last day, then please report it (again) as a bug.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't the actual problem: when it started working the chat widget said "N people chatting" but listing no rooms, and then I talked in the room and the room appeared under that message. But for a long time before that, there was no "people chatting" at all. Outside of that, I agree with your statement of what to do in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I see it on meta and the main site:

[image]

Comment: I don't mean that link, but the one in the right sidebar of the page that's visible without any clicking.